# Is there a way to send mail to "Joe Blow" <joe@blow.com> without adding them to Contacts?

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

How do I send an email to a single person with their first name and last name (not just their email address) without having to add them to my Contacts in the Mail app on my Mac? Is this possible?

Comment: Is this so you have their name pre-registered if they reply? It makes no difference to the sent mail. Each recipient has their own method of resolving email address to other details.

Comment: Given your Answer, I think you want to know how to send an email so that the recipient's name and email address are not automatically added to Contacts. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

OK, figured it out right after I posted this:

1. Copy and paste the email address into the "To" field
2. Right click and do "Edit address"
3. Surround the email with angle brackets: "<>"
4. Add the first and last name in double quotes before to the beginning

Comment: You can mark your own answer as accepted so that this question is marked as answered